# ERROR: InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace - how to avoid that?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I had no problems before, it was all fine, even when watchdog worked and restarted the device, everything worked fine. Until after one of such reboots something happened with partitioning, fixed that with fsck. It threw a bunch of errors, but at least it booted again. After that, I had to recreate the database, it would run only in `innodb_force_recovery=5`. Since then, like almost every time, when watchdog reboots the device, server won't run again, and I am getting `[ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace ...` message in error log. Then I have to run the server again with `innodb_force_recovery=1` and restart it after. Every time! This is annoying! Any ideas how to fix that? Or at least run the database like with `innodb_force_recovery=1` but in normal mode with write permissions?

Comment: Are you saying that you can never run without `innodb_force_recovery` > 0?

Comment: No, that when watchdog reboots the device in random moment, I have to do recovery before starting it in normal mode.

Comment: Your watchdog should gracefully shut down your MySQL server so that it is not in inconsistent state after reboot.

Comment: You sure? It's hardware watchdog. Anyway it does not. I mean... it happens what I described.